# Console Output In Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, process, console

```
CASE 1
    Process processo = new Process();
    processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = "ftp";
    processo.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s:comandos.cmd";
    processo.Start();
    processo.WaitForExit();
    output = processo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();   


CASE 2
AllocConsole();
Process processo = new Process();
processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processo.StartInfo.FileName = "ftp";
processo.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s:comandos.cmd";
processo.Start();
processo.WaitForExit();
output = processo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
FreeConsole();
```

Why the ouput is not the same using the case 1 and 2 ? The Alloc and FreeConsole are functions from kernel32.dll... Im using a windows forms application.

The comandos.cmd connect to the server and use a "dir" command.

Have a way to use AllocConsole() without show the console window ?

First output is:
User xxx
archive1
archive2

cd Folder
dir
quit

Second output is:
open xxx
User xxx
331 User ok
230 Password ok
cd Folder
archive1
archive2
226 transfer complete
xxx bytes received
quit
221 GoodBye

Comment: Hard to guess what's different if you don't describe it.  Just don't write code like this, use the FtpWebRequest class with Method = WebRequestmethods.Ftp.ListDirectory.

Comment: FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse doesn't working, it doesn't list the files of "main directory" example: 111.111.111 only at 111.111.111/folder1...